# Angular 8 - best way to set up 3rd party components once per app?

Tags: angular, components

What is the recommended way to set up 3rd party components?

I use primeng p-table in many different components in my application. I would like to set it up once per whole application - turn on paginator by default, set default number of rows per page etc.

If making every column in p-table sortable by default is also possible - it would be awesome...

Comment: yes, it's possible you can make dynamic components for your table and pagination and then pass dynamic value in that component and set the selector of the component where you want to use this component.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating a component for table separately. I can give you a basic idea and you can develop it according to your requirement.

Say, you create table-component. The table component will have a table and paginator.  But, the contents in that table are passed from some other parent component to table-component.ts. So, in your table-component.ts:

```
@Input()
dataSource = [] // this dataSource is pulled from parent-conponent.ts
```

In your table-component.html:

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]=dataSource>    
 .
 .
 .
 </table>
```

In your parent component, whenever you wanted to display a table, parent-component.html:

```
<table-component [dataSource]='yourArray'>
```

What ever component you are in, call the above one and send your array. It will display the table and this is reusable. Hope this was what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you, I've made a small progress. PrimeNG p-table uses templates to render column headers, table body etc. (source code: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/table/table.ts ). How to define those templates in "my-table-component" and pass them to original p-table? Basic usage of original p-table: https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/table